# Core Data Crash in mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification -> call loop

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a problem with CoreData and I don't know any further. I use it with ICloud and test this on two iPhones.

Now I start my app on both phones one after the other. I add a record in one phone. As soon as both phones switch to "Using local storage: 0" I can see the memory on one phone (the one which receives the notification for the change).

It happens when calling the [self.howRUDocument.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification]; method. When I debug, the stepover mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification will never reach the next line.

```
- (id)initWithDocumentName:(NSString *)documentName {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.documentName = documentName;
        iCloudCommunicator = [ICloudCommunicator sharedInstance];
        [iCloudCommunicator registerForICloudAccountChange:self];
        if ([iCloudCommunicator useICloud]) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(documentChanged:)
                                                         name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                                       object:self.howRUDocument.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) documentChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.howRUDocument.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

This is what I see in the profiler:

[image]

So it is an infinite loop (isn't that the apple address :-D). Has anyone a clue why?

Another strange thing is, that this methods are in a class Model. I have two models extending from this class. For one the merging is working as expected, for the other I get the above exception.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had a bis mess setting up the document. When creating and moving it to cloud I was moving wrong document urls.
Also there was a race condition, so the document tried to open before it was created.

I have this code and it works well:

```
- (id)initWithDocumentName:(NSString *)documentName {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dataChangeListeners = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.documentName = documentName;
        iCloudCommunicator = [ICloudCommunicator sharedInstance];
        [iCloudCommunicator registerForICloudAccountChange:self];
        if ([iCloudCommunicator useICloud]) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(documentChanged:)
                                                         name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                                       object:self.howRUDocument.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) documentChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.howRUDocument.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    [self notifyDataChangeListeners];
}
```